# Deploy both back-end and front-end React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

Suppose I have written a simple registration form app that stores user information on backend database. My frontend is hosted on `localhost:3000`, and my server is on `localhost:4000`. It works perfectly. I initialized a boilerplate with `create-react-app`. My structure is the following:

```
project/
    |
    |-- client/
    |   | ...
    |   | package.json
    |
    |-- server/
    |   | ...
    |   | package.json
```

The thing is that I want to set it up for everyone else on the Internet, and show my progress to a friend. Can I use any free hosting to achieve that, i.e. Github Pages or Heroku? Or do they only support front-end apps?

What I want to have running is when someone fills forms and presses submit my database document would receive new entries. And I could monitor it just like I monitor my database on `localhost:27017`.

I am not at all familiar with deployment. What is the approach to set everything right and sound? Do I need to configure everything from scratch (i.e. tinkering with Babel and Webpack in the beginning) in order to have a fully operational backend and frontend website?

Thank you.

Comment: I would like to suggest you https://ngrok.com/ to show someone else directly from your local while if you would like to play with deployment then for the database, you may give a try to https://mlab.com/ or https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas or any other database as service while Heroku is fine for back-end and front-end

Comment: Okay. I played a little with [ngrok.com](https://ngrok.com). Basically, I only need to open one port `3000` where my frontend is, and it is going to work just fine on server side? I mean entries, and stuff?

Comment: Wow. Actually, it does. They tell me, however, that they work with Nginx. I am going to take a look into that, too. If you wish you could post a comment as an aswer, I'll upvote it.